# Creating polygons from adjacent points using GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas

I have a GeoPandas dataframe `gdf` that looks like the following. Here the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWhUU0tVBazjNrMo7FIO2ma5qI5vsZGB/view?usp=sharing) to the data as `.csv`

```
   ur   geometry
0   1   POINT (12.29632 42.04710)
1   1   POINT (12.30629 42.04710)
2   1   POINT (12.31625 42.04710)
3   1   POINT (12.32621 42.04710)
4   1   POINT (12.33617 42.04710)
```

where `ur=0` or `ur=1`. Here the plot:

[image]

I would like to create a GeoPandas dataframe of polygons connecting all the adjacent points with the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Create points, buffer, dissolve:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely import wkt

df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/bera/Downloads/gdf.csv')
df['geom'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: wkt.loads(x))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df['geom'])
gdf.crs = "EPSG:3857"

gdf.geometry = gdf.buffer(distance=0.008)
gdf = gdf.dissolve(by='ur')
#gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.simplify(tolerance=0.002, preserve_topology=True) #If you want a less "buffered" look

gdf = gdf.reset_index()
gdf[['ur','geometry']].to_file('/home/bera/Downloads/gdf.shp')
```

[image]